# How we can add translation job metadata through customization or TMPlugin code?

Tags: web8.5, translation-manager

I have requirement to send email to Author when translation job completes so I have added translation job metadata using below documentation.

We don't want the Author to enter their email ID manually while sending translation job, so we are looking for solution to update email metadata field through customization or TM plug in code.

Document Link to Add Translation Job Metadata: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-DD563DCE-A639-494B-994D-D3012514C852

Comment: As per my commend below, please update the question with the real business requirement so we can help you find the best solution. Sending emails for Tridion job status from TMS/WS can be problematic due to these systems not having knowledge of the Tridion translation job structure out of the box.

Comment: Ok. My question was, how we can update metadata of translation job. We don't want author to enter manually in metadata field. We want it to be updated by system. Is there any way I can extend metadata tab of translation job and update the field.

Comment: I thought to do it through event handle or TM plug in code to update metadata field of translation job but I am not getting metadata of translation job in translation job object in TM plug in code. I am not sure how to do it through event handler.

Comment: My requirement is to send metadata with email which is not supposed to enter by author. I am looking ways to do it automatically

Comment: Sorry, still looks like an X-Y problem to me. If you do not know what an X-Y problem is, please google it. No one will have a business requirement to "send metadata with email" - that would be a technical requirement someone has come up with (so the Y) in order to solve an actual business requirement (the X). So what is business (X) requirement?

Answer (score 3):

Translation Job Metadata is needed for data you need on translation management system itself.

Since the event for a completed translation job is raised in Tridion you do not need to use translation job metadata. It is of course also possibilities to send the email from the translation management system, but as it will not be aware of Tridion splitting translation jobs into multiple jobs so it will send an email too early in some cases.

So if you are able to find the email address of the user when the email is being send, move this snippet of code into the event handler for the translation job completes. You will have access to id of both the user creating the translation job and the last user modifying it (i.e. the user sending it).

Comment: We want to send translation job metadata to TMS system. We want to do it through code. We have requirement to get email notification from TMS system so we want to send email id's as part of translation job metadata. We don't want Author to put their email id while sending job so we want to automate this.

Comment: Since the TMS system does not know when a Tridion job completes without a lot of extra code I do not think this is a good idea. Please check this is not an X-Y problem: What is the real business requirement? I doubt it is "emails must be send from TMS", it is more likely that the requirement is to receive emails in certain cases (job completion/fail, etc). Once you update your question with the business (not technical) requirements, we can help finding the best technical solution.

Comment: +1 to Lars' points that Tridion is aware of when a job completes and job metadata isn't needed. However you handle the automation, the Event System is a better approach than TM plugin (deprecated since Web 8). Typical places for where to store emails would be user description or AppData.